# Inconsistent behavior between local actor and remote actor

Tags: scala, closures, akka, actor

This is sort of a follow up to an earlier question at [Scala variable binding when used with Actors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441102/scala-variable-binding-when-used-with-actors)

Against others' advice, I decided to make a message containing a closure and mutate the variable that closure is closed under between messages.. and explicitly wait for them.
The environment is akka 1.2 on scala 2.9

Consider the following

```
var minAge = 18
val isAdult = (age: Int) => age >= minAge

println((actor ? answer(19, isAdult)).get) 
minAge = 20
println((actor ? answer(19, isAdult)).get)
```

The message handler for answer essentially applies isAdult to the first parameter (19). 
When actor is local,  I get the answers I expect.

```
true
false
```

But when it is remote, I get

```
false
false
```

I am simply curious why this would be the behavior? I would have expected consistent behavior between the two..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have come across what may (or may not) be considered a problem for a system where the behaviour is specified by rules which are not enforced by the language. The same kind of thing happens in Java. Here:

1. Client: `Data d = rmiServer.getSomeData();`
2. Client: `d.mutate()`

Do you expect the mutation to happen on the server as well? A fundamental issue with any system which involves remote communication, especially when that communication is transparent to a client, is understanding where that communication is occurring and what, exactly, is going on.

- The communication with the actor takes the form of message-passing
- An effect can pass a boundary only by the mechanism of message-passing (that is, the effect must reside within the returned value)
- The actor library may transparently handle the transmission of a message remotely
- If your effect is not a message, it is not happening!

Comment: I understand that remote actors are not able to see the new value without the local agent passing message to the remote actors. But in this case, the second message contains a closure, and the value of the closure should have changed from that in the first message. I am not sure the actor being remote should have anything to do with this behavior..

Comment: I am not sure what you think a *closure* is but it sounds like you have things slightly wrong. It's a closure because it closes over its lexical scope. i.e. you are modifying a value *outside* that block of code.

Answer (score 2):

What you encounter here is what I would call “greediness” of Scala closures: they never close “by-value”, presumably because of the uniform access principle. This means that the closure contains an `$outer` reference which it uses to obtain the value of `minAge`. You did not give enough context to show what the `$outer` looks like in your test, hence I cannot be more precise in how it is serialized, from which would follow why it prints what you show.

*One word, though:* don’t send closures around like that, please. It is not a recipe for happiness, as you acknowledge yourself.